# What is the meaning of "command its obedience" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is the context:

> There are physicists like Lawrence Krauss who think, “Ah, just put in the laws of physics, quantum
>   field theory, and this plus nothing equals the world.” But then one is left with the question
>   of, “Well, what are those laws? Do they somehow exist outside of physical reality and **command its
>   obedience**?”

Does it mean command to her obedients? and if not, can you explain the meaning?

Comment: I command you to obey me. = I command your obedience. obedient is an adjective only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For A to command B's obedience means that B obeys A's commands (in a general, ongoing sense).  For example, a ruler commands the obedience of their subjects in that if they give a command, they can expect it will be obeyed; it describes the relationship, rather than the act.

In this context, it's asking if physical reality obeys these hypothetical 'laws' that exist outside it.